# Call php function from form, and complete form with result

Tags: php, jquery, forms, wordpress, autofill

I am writing a plug-in for Wordpress, but if you are not familiar with Wordpress it shouldn't matter. I have a form I need to fill in, and I have a function that can return all the fields required in the form 95% of the time. The function required a unique ID, the function puts the unique ID into a URL, gets some XML, parses the XML and returns some stuff. It is this stuff I want to auto fill the remaining form fields with.

I therefore need a form button to send the unique ID to my function, and I need to understand how my function can return the stuff to the remaining fields... with or without a page reload?
The user would then check the fields, add additional data manually if required, and then submit.

The one complication is that the URL that the xml comes from is external, and therefore can't be queried by Jquery? Correct or not?
any help much appreciated.

Comment: I have solved this for now, by leaving action empty, so it posts to itself.  I have then added a php function call to sort out the function bit.  and changed the value of the form fields depending on the results of the function.  Integrating into wordpress is seemingly the remaining difficult bit.

Answer (score 1):

If by "external" you mean a cross domain Ajax request, it's possible. See [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function and `jsonp` setting.

Comment: I believe that will only work if the server you're requesting the data from is configured to handle `jsonp` requests. Alternatively, there are plugins which will allow you to make cross-domain GET requests, such as https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

Comment: I do mean cross domain. Can I use my current php functoin with this method?

Comment: @Andrewb I'm not sure about deifwud's note of the server's settings. It would be odd that fetching data from a site needs a specific setting to be enabled. After all, you're just reading a file's info. Maybe someone could confirm this issue. Check this link and it's warnings about `jsonp`: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that very well. What I should have said is the URL you are requesting the data from must be set up to handle `jsonp` requests - also `jsonp` requests return a `json` formatted `object`. If you want to read more about `jsonp` check out http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/ - by far the best article I've come across. Also check out Skacc's answer, there are some really good suggestions in there.

Answer (score 1):

Using AJAX you can POST/GET and with the return you can determine what to do with your form.

For example, using jQuery I convert the data to JSON format and sent it to an external server which responds with a JSON string.  Still within jQuery I iterate through the data and depending on the results throw errors to the specific id's etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JSON then you can use jQuery.

If you must use XML then you need YQL (Yahoo! Query Language). Here is an article for that: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

If you have access to the place that serves the XML then you can use the crossdomain.xml technique: http://code.google.com/p/crossxhr/wiki/CrossXhr

Or you can do a regular ajax to one of your own php pages, that php page gets the XML with curl (or something similar) then returns the result. This way you dont need to do crossdomain request but it takes a little longer.